# Tailwind class is not working after installed

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I try to use CSS, im just install the tailwindcss with npm, and then i build the css and provide the output.css. But, when i use the bg-black class in button for testing, it's still not working.

build command that i use
`tailwindcss -i ./src/style.css -o ./dist/output.css` i put it into script in package.json

Directory file path:
[image]

in `src/style.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

in `tailwind.config.js`

```
    theme: {
      extend: {
        // ...
      },
    },
    plugins: [],
  }
```

in `dist/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css">
    <title>Learn Tailwind</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="bg-black">Awesome</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The HTML in browser result:**

[image]

Answer (score 47):

You can simply change the following codes in your style.css and it will work.

from this

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

to this

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Rest of the codes remain same. Only the above needs to be changed and you're good to go. This usually happens in tailwind v3.

Hope the answer helps you.

Comment: hi @Code Ware Tech could you please pass a ling to the source that explains why did this work?

Comment: I had to do this to get Tailwind working in a brand new Rails 7 app made with `--css tailwind`. I'd love to know how this works and why it didn't just work "out of the box"

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me as well (fresh Rails 7 app). I'd love to understand it more, too. For now, problem solved.

Comment: Worked for me. Installed Tailwind on an old NextJS project.

Comment: Hi all, The above solution is compatible for new and old version of tailwind css. The problem occurs because of the tailwind version is not compatible with the framework version you're using. Hope it helps.

Comment: I had the same issue as well. This fixed my problem, but I don't know why.

Comment: I have added same way but still none of 3 import default class of tailwind

Answer (score 36):

**Update (Dec 2022)**: As it sounds, try to restart your editor. I had everything in check (configuration, imports) and it didn't work. When I restarted my editor (VSCode) classes got recognized.

**Original:**

I had the same issue. it is to do with your tailwind.config.js
Make sure you have the [content list](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration) pointing to your html files that are using tailwind. (see code below to look at all files with html at one level down)

Then run the command:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Ensure you don't get any warning messages about invalid paths.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./*/*.html', ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: This hint helped me out. If you are using tailwind with vue, don't forget to insert the .vue extension in here. That is my content-array (using vite with ts enabled):

content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,vue}",
  ],

Comment: @Michael this help me out with the current latest version of vue and tailwind, they need to add this detail to the documentations in vite

Answer (score 16):

1. Go to `tailwind.config.js` file. On the very first line, you will find `content`, add location the of your html files

   ```
   module.exports = {
      content: ['./index.html'],
      theme: {
        extend: {
          primary : '#243c5a', 
          secondary : {
            100: '#243c5a',
          }
        },
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
   ```
2. Go to cmd and run command `npm run build-css` to rebuild and show any error your code has.

Read more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration)

Comment: I went to the content line of the tailwind.config.js and wrote the exact html file name within the brackets and then in the terminal I wrote npm run build. This is what worked for me!

Comment: Following up to say this worked for me asw!

Answer (score 5):

We need to edit the folder file global.css

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: solutions for tailwind CSS file.

Answer (score 5):

**In general tailwindcss does not recommend using dynamic classes as they mentioned in their documentation [here is a link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names).**

> Don't construct class names dynamically:

```
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
```

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.

Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:

> Always use complete class names

```
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
```

Comment: the reason is because tailwindcss scans for classes using regular expressions and then generates a related css in response, so you should provide a complete class names as mentioned above.

Comment: This is exactly what I did wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Came across your answer while searching.

Answer (score 4):

Those using vite + react add this to your tailwind.config.cjs:

```
content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you are using build command and put it in your `package.json`, that is right. But did you run `npm run build` then?

Comment: Also good to have the --watch flag on the tailwind build so that it automatically builds the tailwind whenever theres changes to the tailwind.config

Answer (score 2):

I see you import "output.css" in your code but you necessarily need to import your tailwind css file. Ex:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
```

See doc: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: 1. Check your path file. 2. Is your output.css nicely fill with css equivalent of your classes ? If no -> check stage 4 of the doc. / if yes -> Check the import of your output.css

Comment: And is see you are using the command tailwindcss -i ./src/style.css -o ./dist/output.css ! You need to add the tag --watch at the end if you don't want to send the command for all changes you will made.

Comment: Im also having issues. I figured this would be an easy step but I have been on it for multiple days but it just won't work

Answer (score 2):

In `tailwind.config.js` you have to target your output elements like this

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pubblic/index.html", <!-- my Html and my js file-->
    "./pubblic/index.js"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

after this, you can run your script

```json
"tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/style.css"
```

this should work

Answer (score 2):

none of the answers above helped me.

i followed the official docs from tailwind for Vitejs and it did not work.

i needed to add 'postcss.config.js' file as follow:

```js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

and than restart my dev server, then it worked.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me too - also using Vite.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to answer directly but instead help debug.

1. test if their CDN version works by using

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it should work.

2. If it does, go to that website (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2/dist/tailwind.min.css) and copy paste everything and put it into your `output.css` or whatever name you gave the file you are trying to locally import.
3. Test if it works

- if it does -> then the issue is that your build process isnt correclty building your output css
- if it does not -> then the issue is that your `output.css` or whatever you call it wasnt found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a [Jumpstart Pro](https://jumpstartrails.com/) app, make sure you are using `bin/dev` instead of `rails s` to run your app. That was my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue while all my configurations were right,
this solved the problem for me : package.json --> tap the small 'Debug' on top of 'Scripts' or run "npm run build-css "

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i have a simple solution just take the tailwind.config.js, package-lock.json and index.html files and insert them to **src** folder, hope this will help for others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone. So I had this issue that everything was installed correctly from the official docs from tailwind. But the styles were not being reflected. (create my project with `create-react-app` as usual)

When I say the whole installation went fine I really mean everything, like content inside the config, `tailwindcss, postcss, autoprefixer` installation and included the base tailwind

```
@tailwind base; 
@tailwind components; 
@tailwind utilities;
```

styles in then `index.css`.

The issue on my end was I just had to update the react scripts with this command:

**`npm install react-scripts@latest`**

My previous version was `2.x` and after installation `5.x` was installed and everything is working fine now.

PS: And tailwind directives can be added either way, both works for me
Option 1 (I have gone with this one)

```
@tailwind base; 
@tailwind components; 
@tailwind utilities;
```

OR
option 2

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure who needs to see this

ensure the tailwind config does not have a `prefix` set

```
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-', // with prefix use "tw-bg-red-500"
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You might only need to restart the app so that tailwindcss configuration takes effect.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of importing tailwind to your project is to **import it into a js/ts file**, if your stack allows you to directly import CSS files to JS, like in React applications.

```
 import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
```