# Tailwind classes are not working after installed

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'd like to begin with stating that this question's title is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577297/tailwind-class-is-not-working-after-installed) but I tried the answers there but they won't work.

I first tried Tailwind from their official CLI guide, but that wouldn't work so I followed [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFgzHOX84xQ) for the set-up but Tailwind still won't work.

In the previously mentioned question someone noted that you need to be very specific in the path from `tailwind.cofig.js` to your HTML, but I did this.

My `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./*.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And here is a screenshot of my folder:

[image: My folder]

This is the content of `input.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And this of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <h1 class="text-sky-400">Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And to run it, I followed the YouTube tutorial and added this to my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./css/main.css",
    "watch": "tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./css/main.css --watch"
  },
```

And use `npm run watch`.

When I build it, it just shows the HTML without the Tailwind styling.

What am I doing wrong? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Change this code in the package.json file:

```
"watch": "tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./css/main.css --watch"
```

To :

```
"watch": "npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./css/main.css --watch"
```

I hope this solves the problem