# The Tailwind CSS doesn't work even the classes reflect on the HTML Tag

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I just don't know what went wrong here, the tailwind never works at the first try.  [In this screenshot shows that the html tag actually changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpVe1.jpg)

I already changed my global.css configuration to this

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

According to this answer at [stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577297/tailwind-class-is-not-working-after-installed), I also already added some content in the `tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  **content: [
      "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
      "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
      "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],**
  mode: "jit",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        inter: ["Inter", "sans-serif"],
      },
      colors: {
        "black-100": "#2B2C35",
        "primary-blue": {
          DEFAULT: "#2B59FF",
          100: "#F5F8FF",
        },
        "secondary-orange": "#f79761",
        "light-white": {
          DEFAULT: "rgba(59,60,152,0.03)",
          100: "rgba(59,60,152,0.02)",
        },
        grey: "#747A88",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        'pattern': "url('/pattern.png')",
        'hero-bg': "url('/hero-bg.png')"
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Also I was trying to do this command
**npx tailwind -i tailwind.css -o ./layouts/styles.css --watch** it can't find the path, and then i changed it to **npx tailwindcss -i build src/app/global.css -o public/styles.css** and it says

```
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Anyway, I am using pnpm command, and i did trying to use pnpm instead of npx with both of those command, but still not working as well. Last part, below is my page.tsx code:

```
'use client'

import React from 'react';

export default function Home ()  {
  return (
    <div className="text-center mt-8">
     <h2 className='text-2xl font-semibold'>Hello brow</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am expecting the tailwind css works as it classes already reflect to the HTML tag when I inspect the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it, I have to rebuild the node modules using command `npm run dev` with the **'run'** it will [rebuild](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) and will notice that we just install tailwind css in our existing next js app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but three things to make sure Tailwind works are:

- Global.css need

> @tailwind base; 
>  @tailwind components; 
> @tailwind utilities;

- _app.js

> import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'

- tailwind config

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        git: {
          50: "#c778dd33",
          100: '#c778dd',
        },
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: that does not work

Comment: After run > npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
Did you run > npx tailwindcss init -p already?

Comment: Created Tailwind CSS config file: tailwind.config.js
postcss.config.js already exists. well it says already exist

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem when changing from bootstrap to tailwindcss. Tailwind classes were showing in the HTML tag when I was inspecting the elements.

I found that I was not importing the `global.css`. After manually importing the global.css in App.jsx file everything was working as it is.