# Tailwindcss not being enabled

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I created a react project and ran it to test. But it looks like tailwindcss is not enabled. I'm not able to style elements.

App.jsx

```
const App = () => {
   return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="text-3xl underline">
        Hello world!
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

tailwind.config.jsx

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
import { vitePluginTailwindcss } from 'vite-plugin-tailwindcss';
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    './public/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
  ], 
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [vitePluginTailwindcss],
}
```

I added mode:jit and plugin to try and fix, but not fixed. There are no errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind class is not working after installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577297/tailwind-class-is-not-working-after-installed)

Answer (score 0):

try to change the tailwind.config.jsx file to:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts}", "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the `postcss.config.cjs` file to the project.

and add

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Comment: Looks like that was the issue, but I had to start from the from scratch with installing tailwind with postcss. Got it fixed now, thanks